# How to blur a div (box)

Tags: html, css, blur

How can I apply a Gaussian blur using CSS to a DIV which contains text. Basically, what I want to achieve is to have the box with a gaussian blur but the text in a normal way. Can this be done? I don't know how, I've been trying but I just can't.

Example:
Like I have my div at opacity: 0.75 I would like my div to be transparent but with gaussian blur, since in the background I have a moving image, so I want the box to be blurred.

Comment: I recently attempted this and do not think it's possible.

Answer (score 2):

Apply following CSS to your block:

```
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
```

However, this property works only in modern browsers: [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: The effect wan't what I wanted. What I want is that the background of the box which has text is transparent but blurred and that text isn't, and when I put that, it blurs everything. want to see code?

I want something like this http://blurjs.com/ like the first box.

Comment: @user3614311 link is broken can you post an image?

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't think you can achieve what you are looking for without some extra `div` or even better a pseudo-element. My suggestion would be:

```
div {
  position:relative;
  width: 10em;
  height: 20em;
  padding: 1em;
}
div::before {
  content: '';
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
  background: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/6c/Some_Girls.png);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Your question is not too clear though so I am not sure if this is what you are looking for...
Pen: http://codepen.io/marczking/pen/dqxwG